# How can I display column values in two columns?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using SQL Developer and currently have a table like this:

```
PROD | SER_NUM | PROD_DESC
Xxxx | 255236  | 'BLK'
Yyyy | 785412  | 'RED'
Zzzz | 254861  | 'BLK'
Wwww | 985465  | 'RED'
```

and I need to display it like this:

```
PROD |  BLK   |  RED   |
Xxxx | 255236 |        |
Yyyy |        | 785412 |
Zzzz | 254861 |        |
Wwww |        | 985465 |
```

Comment: Are `blk` and `red` the only two `prod_desc` values?  So the output will always have three columns?  Or are you trying to do a dynamic pivot where the number of columns changes as new `prod_desc` values get added?  What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  select prod, 
  case when prod_desc ='RED' then ser_num else '' end As RED, 
  case when prod_desc='BLK' then ser_num else '' end BLK  
  from your_table;
```